# Subseting in chunks in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Daniil\\Desktop\\dw_payments'
#list of all df:
all_files = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
all_payments_data = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = []
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,index_col = None,chunksize = 200000)
    df_f = df[df['CUSTOMER_NO'] == 20069675]
    df_f = pd.concat(df_f,ignore_index = True)
    dfs.append(df_f)

all_payments_data = pd.concat(dfs)
```

As you see in the line `df_f = df[df['CUSTOMER_NO'] == 20069675]` i want to select the specific customer in one chunk and then merge it to the empty data frame. And I want to repeat the process many times(there are a lot of files).

But it throws me an error:

```
TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is it a big file? You can omit chunksize if it isn't.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ very big. That is the problem

Comment: Ah, using chunksize makes `df` iterables, not iterators. Try `df_f = [x[x['CUSTOMER_NO'] == 20069675] for x in df]` after reading `df = pd.read_csv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need iterate by [`TextFileReader`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk), filter and append to `df_s`. Last only once `concat`.

***Notice*** - Structure of all files has to be same (same columns names in same order)

```
df_s = []
for file in all_files:
    txt = pd.read_csv(file,index_col = None,chunksize = 200000)
    for df in txt:
        df_s.append(df[df['CUSTOMER_NO'] == 20069675])

df_f = pd.concat(df_s,ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: If they're using chunksize... there's may be a reason, so concatenation will cause memory error. Maybe it's better to iterate over chunks and append.

Comment: The problem is exactly in memory error. Do you think your solution will solve this problem?

Comment: Please check last version of my answer.

Comment: Works great! Thank you:)